# When calling a function from another file the app crashes

Tags: ios, swift3, swrevealviewcontroller

**I am new to Swift so this will hopefully be something simple but nothing that I have found has helped.**

I am using SWRevealViewController to add a side menu onto my app, it basically creates a table view controller onto the side of the regular view controller. When the user taps on one of the cells I want to be able to call a function that is in the regular view controller.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  ViewController().testFunction()
}
```

This then calls the function:

```
func testFunction() {
    button1.setTitle("TEST", for: .normal)
}
```

Now, the app calls this function correctly but I am left with the error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

If I ask the function to Print("test") instead of changing the button title, that works absolutely fine. When I try calling the function from the same regular view controller there are no errors and the button changes text.

Answer (score 1):

The cause for crash is this line:

```
ViewController().testFunction()
```

What you do is you create a brand new instance of ViewController and call a method that does something with one of its properties. Now, we can safely assume that your `button1` is a button you created in Interface Builder - therefore it doesn't exist by the time you are trying to access it.

What you should be doing is call this method on some already existing instance of ViewController, not creating a brand new instance of it (which doesn't make much sense anyway - it's not in the navigation stack, it just exists locally in your `didSelectRowAt`)

Comment: How would I go about selecting the instance of ViewController that has already been called?